# How many permutation of 6 elements that can each be oriented in 2 ways?

Tags: permutations

I've trying to find the answer to this but failing. I understand that if the order matters, there are 6! permutations of 6 elements, or 720.  But I'm trying to figure out how many permutations there are if each of the six elements is oriented in one of two ways.  Like if I have 6 arrows where each arrow can be pointing either right or left.  How many permutations are there in this scenario?  Any help someone can provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: How many ways are there of orienting the arrows if you keep the elements in a particular order?

Comment: 2 ways right or left (R or L).  So one set (if each arrow is labelled A to F) could be: AR, BR, CL, DL, ER, FR, and another could be AL, BR, CL, DR, ER, FR.  A third could be DR, FR, AL, CR, ER, BL.

Comment: There are 6 arrows, each can be oriented in 2 ways. So how many total ways can you orient the 6 arrows (for the arrows in a *particular* order)

Comment: So assuming the order of the arrows always stays the same (ABCDEF), I manually wrote out all the ways the arrows could be either R or L and came up with 64 different ways: R(6),L(0) = 1 way;  R(5),L(1) = 6 ways;  R(4),L(2) = 15 ways;  R(3),L(3) = 20 ways;  R(2),L(4) = 15 ways;  R(1),L(5) = 6 ways;  R(0),L(6) = 1 way.  Is there math that says this is right or wrong?

Comment: So $1+6+15+20+15+6+1=64$. This is $2^6$ ways since each of the six arrows can independently be oriented one of two ways.  And you correctly say there are $6!=720$ ways of ordering the arrows.  Can you now see the answer to your original question?

Comment: Since for each of the 720 arrangements of the 6 there are 64 possibilities for the orientation, I believe it is 720 x 64 = 46,080.